# How to use auto Correction view for custom key-board extention ios8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to implement Auto Correction in Custom Keyboard in ios 8?
I have created Custom Keyboard but I am not able to do auto correction in the Custom Keyboard.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not personally tried creating a custom keyboard, I am basing this answer on what I can see in the documentation.

In your keyboard, create a property called entries of type [AnyObject] (Array of AnyObjects).

In your init method, or wherever you create the keyboard, call this method:

```
requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion(completionHandler: {
    lexicon in 
    self.entries = lexicon.entries
})
```

I suspect that entries is actually an array of Strings or NSStrings, but it could be a dictionary or some other type. When testing this out, try figuring out what type is actually contained in entries before figuring out your logic.

I do not believe there is a way to get Apple's default autocorrect options currently. However, this WWDC talk gives insight about how they made autocorrect work in the original iPhone OS (around the 30 minute mark).

He mentions using a binary search of the array, which leads me to believe that this array is sorted. Of course, much could have changed since the first iPhone came out...

Good luck figuring out this new API!

Comment: Could you post a link to the WWDC talk?